# Longest Increasing Subsequence - LeetCode 300

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming, memoization

Referring to the question: [Longest Increasing Subsequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/description/)

Here is my code with recursion that works but is too slow as it is not doing memoization:

```
class Solution {
public static int recurse(int prev, int curr, int[]nums) {
    if(curr == nums.length) return 0;

    int elect=0;
    int ignore=0;
    if(prev==-1 || nums[prev]<nums[curr]) {
        elect = 1 + recurse(curr,curr+1,nums);
    }
    ignore = recurse(prev,curr+1,nums);
    return Math.max(elect,ignore);
}
public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {
    return recurse(-1,0,nums);
}
```

The function `lengthOfLIS` invokes my recursion as `recurse(-1,0,nums)`

The thing I am struggling for hours is that I want to use a 1 dimensional array that stores cached result for the sub-array for memoization. For example my `dp` array if I were to create one of size `nums.length` should be 1d. Is that possible? My attempts have failed and I get incorrect results. Here is the incorrect code
(Note that this snippet does not show the init code for dp array)

```
    public static int recurse3(int prev, int curr, int nums[]) {
    if(curr == nums.length) return 0;
    if(dp2[curr]!=-1) return dp2[curr];
    int op1 = 0;
    if(prev==-1 || nums[curr]>nums[prev]) {
        op1 = 1+recurse3(curr, curr+1, nums);
    }
    int op2=recurse3(prev,curr+1,nums);
    dp2[curr] = Math.max(op1,op2);
    return Math.max(op1,op2);
}
```

Comment: At each call, you can either skip the element at position `curr`, or keep it. But you can only keep it if `nums[curr]>nums[prev]`, so the result also depends on `prev`, so you cannot simply store it in `dp2[curr]`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on why